# How can dd over ssh report read speeds exceeding the network bandwidth?

Tags: linux, ssh, pipe, dd

I am executing this command to test a connection from a remove server:

```
ssh -l user $IP "dd if=/dev/zero count=3500 bs=1M status=progress" > /dev/null
```

This shows progress reports of the form

```
3145728000 bytes (3,1 GB, 2,9 GiB) copied, 276,047 s, 11,4 MB/s
```

so apparently, `dd` reads at 11mb per second. The network bandwidth however is known to cap out below ~20mbits, so this cannot be the amount of data actually received.

`iftop` on the receiving machine shows throughputs around ~300 kbits, which is much less than is possible, but more realistic.

**Question:** What does `dd`'s progress status actually mean when piped over an ssh connection? Is data dropped when the receiving end cannot keep up? What is happening exactly?

Comment: `iperf` is normally used to test the connection speed.

Comment: I know, this isn't the point of the question, however.

Comment: Side note. When measuring network speeds be sure to use correct units. You're mixing MB and kb (not necessarily wrongly) along with mb (which is definitely wrong but probably intended to be Mb). And then there's the whole issue of whether you're intending MB to be 10^x or 2^y (MB vs MiB).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SSH can be operated as a compressed protocol, and judging by your results, it is enabled as such by default in your distribution or configuration (or you are using `ssh -C`). As such, your stream of zeroes compresses nicely into something much more compact -- from your readings, with a compression ratio of about 300: the end result being about 0.3% of the original size. For that reason, it's not really a great choice for testing network speed, since it can take little network bandwidth to produce a huge result on the receiver.

You can turn off compression on demand with `-o Compression=no` on the command line, or permanently for a connection by specifying `Compression no` in your SSH client config.

Another option is to use something more basic, like `netcat`, which doesn't implement compression, authentication, or similar, although I wouldn't generally recommend using it for real-world file transfers for that reason.

Comment: Also, if you use `/dev/urandom` in lieu of `/dev/zero`, then it will be extremely difficult or impossible to compress, so you won't need to worry too much about specific tools spotting a huge stream of zeros and collapsing them.

Comment: @Kevin That said, /dev/urandom isn't a good source to test your network bandwidth necessarily, because it itself can become the bottleneck -- even if entropy is not exhausted.

Comment: @ChrisDown: urandom doesn't block when entropy is exhausted. It does consume some additional CPU, but the network is slower than the CPU by multiple orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Kevin I'm pretty sure you've misread what I said -- I explicitly said it's not about entropy in the final part of the sentence to avoid that comment :-) urandom can often be significantly slower than the network regardless of entropy, for example, my link is 10Gbps, but urandom is nowhere near that -- on a i7-7600U, it's about 35MiB/s.

Comment: @ChrisDown: Sorry, when I read "even if X doesn't happen" I tend to interpret that as meaning "also, X could happen, and that would be a problem as well as what I've already described."

Comment: Thanks, i had used /dev/zero specifically because I though /dev/urandom was "limited"

Comment: @oarfish You can use  `/dev/random` instead of `/dev/urandom`. Or just pipe the entire HDD or RAM into the stream. I'm sure there's enough random garbage there to show some slowdowns on the network.